# Show loader while fetching data in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a loader.component.ts with the selector `<app-loader>`.

This Tag is in main-compontent.html and shows up.

```
<app-loader *ngIf="!showLoader === true">
```

I want, that the loader should just show up, while i fetching data.

I fetch data with following Code:

```
showLoader = true;    
ngOnInit() {
        this.httpService.getOffer()
          .subscribe(
            data => this.offers = data
          )
        this.showLoader = false;
      }
```

As you can see, is the showLoader variable on true, and after fetching the data it should be false, but it don't works. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `this.showLoader = false;` into the `subscribe` block's `success` and `err` functions. Because of the javascript's async feature, your `showLoader` gets set to `False` before the backend call.

And a simple `ngIf` condition would be better.

```
<app-loader *ngIf="showLoader">
```

Answer (score 1):

You most likely want to hide the spinner *after the data is received* or *an error occured*

```
showLoader = true;    

ngOnInit() {
  this.httpService.getOffer()
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.offers = data;
          this.showLoader = false;
        },
        error => this.showLoader = false
      )
}
```